# If MSSQL Table Column is NULL, Change CSS Style Using JS using PHP If Statement is Not Working

Tags: php, html, css, sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a PHP Query to get an image name from my MSSQL table column. The queried image name is put into an `<img>` tag. If the column is empty, it should set the empty column to the image `noimageishereforgbmtrailerserviceltd999.png`, which is a blank `.png` image and make the link unclickable. I am doing this to essentially hide the image from the user if there is no image set, so the user doesn't see a big X inside of where an image should be. The code currently changes the column to `noimageishereforgbmtrailerserviceltd999.png` correctly, but does not change the css styles of the link around it. Here is the PHP code I'm using:

```
$job_posname = "SELECT * FROM new_trailers1 WHERE orderid = '$sn'";
$query=mssql_query( $job_posname, $connection);
$array=mssql_fetch_assoc($query);

        $job_posname7=stripslashes($array['photo1']);

        if ($job_posname7['photo1']===NULL || ctype_space($job_posname7['photo1'])){
            $job_posname7 = "noimageishereforgbmtrailerserviceltd999.png";
            echo "<script>document.getElementById('picca2').style.pointer-events='none';</script>";
            echo "<script>document.getElementById('picca2').style.cursor='default';</script>";
        } else {
            $job_posname7=stripslashes($array['photo1']);
        }

    ?> 

<a id="picca2" href="unitimages/<? echo $job_posname7; ?>" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img id="pica2" src="unitimages/<? echo $job_posname7; ?>" width=50 height=50></a>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you default the noimageishereforgbmtrailerserviceltd999.png on all columns, and just change it if the image exists on the database? I am assuming you are generating the columns dynamically.

Or, just add a class on a PHP variable if the condition is set.

Make a .class in css and just call it depending on what you need.

For example

```
$job_posname = "SELECT * FROM new_trailers1 WHERE orderid = '$sn'";
$query=mssql_query( $job_posname, $connection);
$array=mssql_fetch_assoc($query);

    $job_posname7=stripslashes($array['photo1']);

    if ($job_posname7['photo1']===NULL || ctype_space($job_posname7['photo1'])){
        $job_posname7 = "noimageishereforgbmtrailerserviceltd999.png";
        echo "<script>document.getElementById('picca2').style.pointer-events='none';</script>";
        echo "<script>document.getElementById('picca2').style.cursor='default';</script>";
       $my_css_class_that_hides_image = "hide";
    } else {
        $job_posname7=stripslashes($array['photo1']);
    }

?> 

<a id="picca2" href="unitimages/<? echo $job_posname7; ?>" class="<? echo $my_css_class_that_hides_image; ?>" onclick="swap(this); return false;"><img id="pica2" src="unitimages/<? echo $job_posname7; ?>" width=50 height=50></a>
```

... And define it on your style sheet:

```
.hide{
       /** Style here **/
 }
```